# How to create pdf file using Java without using any external libraries?

Tags: java, pdf

Is there a way to create a PDF file without using a third-party library, like iText, Apache PDFBox, PDFJet and so on ?

Comment: That is not simple, that's why there are libraries for this. PDF is not a simple format like a text file. If you really want to do this, you'll have to study what the PDF format looks like and implement it in your code. It will not be easy.

Comment: Sure, go to freelancer.com or similar and pay someone to do your work for you. They'll charge a reasonable price. This is a huge undertaking though so expect several hundred US dollars minimum. The point of SO is to post what particular issue you have with your code, not do a very complex project for you. Here I'll start you off: public static void main(String[] args) {     You're on your way now!

Comment: @RossC - Several tens thousands of dollars would be more appropriate if he is going to create a PDF without using external libraries.

Comment: All above comments very well explain necessity of PDF generating libraries. But In case you are asking this question only out of curiosity & understanding like me then you can check this article that I created purely out of curiosity. But for professional work please prefer libraries.  http://itsallbinary.com/2018/12/07/generate-pdf-in-java-from-scratch-without-any-library/

Answer (score 10):

If you really want to do this, download a copy of the [PDF specification](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference.pdf), and read it.  (It is only 978 pages ... it won't take that long to read ...)  Then design and implement a program that generates a byte stream that conforms to the specified format and contains the information you want to output with a suitable layout, etcetera.

You could probably produce a simple "hello world" document in a week or three.  But my estimate is that it would take you *years* (and many versions) to get to the level of sophistication of one of the existing libraries.

---

A better idea is to not waste your time reinventing the wheel.