# Export contents of JTextpane to pdf

Tags: java, pdf, export, jtextpane

I am writing a text editor much like wordpad and I want my users to export my jtextpane to a PDF. I don't want to use a external library if I can help it. I only want to export as PDF, I don't want to overwrite, read, or edit any current PDFs. I can post code If I need to but I think the question Is clearly defined.

I am a beginner at java so maybe I missed something.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the possible duplicates of this question?
[Q:-Create-PDF-with-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355025/create-pdf-with-java)

Comment: I did, all the answers there use external library(s), I was hoping for something built in.

Comment: As far as I'm aware there's no built-in way to do it. You'd have to write your own implementation (which I advise against) if you _really_ don't want to use an external library.

Comment: @onelittleprogrammer Check this and draw your own conclusions [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739953/how-to-create-pdf-file-using-java-without-using-any-external-libraries)

Comment: thanks for the link @TimeToCode, have you guys ever used Apache PDFBox? I'd rather not use iText because of licensing.

Comment: @onelittleprogrammer I've never used before Apache PDFBox , but I think it isn't difficult to use , there are many examples for use.

Comment: Ok, thanks. make your comment into an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a PDF file with no external libraries is very complicated, you can check the following link and create your own conclusions.

It is best to use an external library to deploy Java.

[How to create pdf file using Java without using any external libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739953/how-to-create-pdf-file-using-java-without-using-any-external-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas on how to do it:

You need to create your own [Graphics2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html). Then you `paint` your `JTextPane` on it. If you use a library, you can make it easier to write this part, but if not, you will need to implements the [PDF specifications](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html). You can inspire from existing libraries like [VectorGraphics2D](http://trac.erichseifert.de/vectorgraphics2d/)

However, the real issue remains the fonts management. But if you don't mind using the default PDF fonts, it might be feasible.